# Develop algorithm to analyze words

Tags: algorithm, nlp, data-mining, text-mining

I have am working on a project where I have seven "posts." The posts are just a sentence or two about the subject. What I need to do is to develop an algorithm which looks through the posts and identifies certain trends.
For example, "A is good but causes B." I need to develop an algorithm which would identify the link between A and B.

However, as you may be able to tell from my sub par description, I have no idea how to address this problem. Can anybody point me in the right direction? I looked at data mining but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

Comment: Indeed, this is not much data mining (beyond detecting which link is significant), but mostly a natural language processing challenge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are asking is a hot research topic in text mining and natural language processing. However, your question is too general imo.

The simplest thing you could start with might be identifying the words that frequently appear together in a sentence (or consecutive sentences). That would at least provide you with some kind of a correlation. Look into Association Rule Learning as user1161595 suggested. Clustering techniques might be of help too. To begin with, have a look at [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and [text clustering](http://www2.parc.com/istl/projects/ia/sg-clustering.html).

To extract relationships between the words, you need to dive deep into natural language processing. You can use [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_q=twitter%20trend&num=10&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_occt=any&as_sauthors=&as_publication=&as_ylo=&as_yhi=&as_sdt=1&as_subj=eng&as_sdtf=&as_sdts=5&btnG=Search%20Scholar&hl=en) for searching related research on text mining, trend analysis and information retrieval.

In addition, the following links might give you an idea of what you are dealing with:

- [Datamining Twitter](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/dec/05/monday-note-twitter) - an article on The Guardian
- [How to Use Twitter for Information Mining](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=5728)
- [Text Mining and Twitter](http://practicalquant.blogspot.com/2010/04/text-mining-and-twitter.html)
- [Text Data Mining With Twitter And R](http://heuristically.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/text-data-mining-twitter-r/) - mentions a Python module written for this purpose.

As for the implementation, you might look into the open source frameworks mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_mining#Open_source). Furthermore, there are lots of machine learning and NLP libraries out there.

Last but not least, I believe there is a good chance that something similar to what you are looking for has already been implemented somewhere by someone. So a through Google search with the right keywords might get you what you want without diving deep into research.

Answer (score 7):

There are several common data mining techniques you can use. The most straightforward is something called [Association Rule Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning).

Association Rule Learning identifies things that tend to appear together. Grocery stores use this method to mine data from grocery store receipts to determine which items are typically purchased together so that they can be placed near eachother in the store. i.e. Chips and Salsa, Graham Crackers, Marshmallows and Chocolate, Diapers and Beer... etc

Comment: Diapers and beer, if that isn't worth a vote, nothing is. You sure know how to party. :)